# From Sql Database to Azure Storage Emulator

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have a Sql database and I have to put it in my Azure Storage Emulator (In `Storage > Development > Tables`); how can I do it? In Visual Studio I don't find any possibility to import, for example, a `.bacpac` file.

**UPDATE:**

I discovered that the database should not be put in there, but then how do I properly simulate Azure storage and my Sql database as well?

Comment: Why do you need to "simulate" your database? Couldn't you just target an actual database? You could also use a local on-premises SQL Server database.

Comment: I need to "simulate" because i do not have an Azure Account and i am developing and app that will have an Azur Cloud for the database and the storage. What am i doing wrong? In visual studio there is the "Azure Storage emulator" but is only for the storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify: Azure Storage (Tables, Blobs, Queues) is completely different from SQL Azure databases.

If you use the latest version of SQL Express it's very very similar to SQL Azure and fine for most development needs.

There isn't a SQL Azure simulator that I know of - but it's really easy to get a FREE 30 day Azure account and I would strongly suggest you do some development and testing against that: SQL Azure has far more connection issues (no connection, handshake problems, lags) than a database that is local to the app, and you need to be prepared for this (investigate Transient Fault Handling strategies).

You can work locally and connect to your SQL Azure instance = a 'real' SQL Azure simulation.

Answer (score 0):

When developing locally for Azure SQL Database, please use [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/Products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx) - it is the relational database equivalent for Azure Storage Emulator (Azure Blob, Queue, and Table).

Comment: if I understand it by installing SQL Server Express i will have I will have both Azure Database and the Azure Storage?